# How to recognize what coding language is used when notepad++ shows strange symbols?

Tags: windows

I opened this file in notepad++, but it does only show gibberish in the first 2 lines of the file. So when I change some values that are shown in normal text, and I save it, the file has become unreadable for the original program.

How do I detect what language this is?

I've tried multiple encode/decoders online and notepad++ and asked a developer for help but he didn't know the answer for this.

W v e F i l e     ¸›U    P r o j e c t . x m l          Àv    Yí     õ:NQÿ
       @@                      Ö Ø     Àv                                    0               0í     @       Xî      }ž     î     …Œ@             }ž     î     ê¶C     Èî     Èî     €î     …Œ@     ¸›U      }ž    ¸›U     0Ò›     Øî     (A     €î     …Œ@                   X[x    (A     Øî      }ž            Öí     î             ¸›U      }ž            Öí    ¸›U     Q‰ˆ     Ð­ì    @[x    8ï     p õ    =k

File is corrupted when I open it with the original program.

Comment: Are you sure the file is a text file meant to be read by humans ? If so, switch between _Encoding_ menu entries (the first ones, not the ones starting with "convert to" after the menu separator) and see if any makes your file readable.

Comment: Hi Stphane, Thank you for the answer. I tried the multiple encoding entries and they didnt help. The file isn't meant for humans, it's used as a source file that a program uses. I would like to edit the source file. Opening the software and editing it that way isn't really an option for me.

Comment: What kind of file are you dealing with? I mean the first two lines look like special binary headers which might only be recognizable by a specific application.